# Placeholder in JTextField - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

How to put a placeholder JTextArea? I do not want to use a label , I think the placeholder is more elegant.

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();

    JTextField txtSfas = new JTextField();
    TextPrompt txtSfas = new TextPrompt("First Name", txtSfas);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtSfas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    txtSfas.setColumns(2);

}
```

[image]

error:

> TextPrompt cannot be resolved to a type

[image: error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SwingX](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases) library which can be used alongside normal Swing takes cares of this when you initialize a JXTextField and does the same for JXTextArea too.

```
JXTextField text = new JXTextField("Your Prompt Here");
text.setPrompt("New Prompt");
frame.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking for something like this? [Text prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/)

Comment: This is exactly what I try , but as I am layman in programming , I could not apply to my code, you can help me with this , please?

Comment: (1+) @PauloRoberto, did you download the code to your machine and put it in a directory with your other code?

Comment: @camickr TextPrompt cannot be resolved to a type                
I edited the question and the code.

Comment: @PauloRoberto as camickr said, you should download the code at http://www.camick.com/java/source/TextPrompt.java create the class then import it